# Parse.com Error: "This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done."

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform, android-adapter

I am struggling with a very weird Parse (Parse.com) problem:

When I use the usual list.setAdapter(Adapter);, I get the Error: "This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done."

Here is my code:

```
 private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> Adapter;

 private CommentListAdapter CommentListAdapter;

  Adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Activity");
  Adapter.setTextKey("title");

  // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
  CommentListAdapter = new CommentListAdapter(this);

  // Initialize ListView and set initial view to Adapter
  CommentList.setAdapter(Adapter);
  Adapter.loadObjects();

  if (CommentList.getAdapter() == Adapter) {
       CommentList.setAdapter(CommentListAdapter);
       CommentListAdapter.loadObjects();
  }else{
       CommentList.setAdapter(Adapter);
       Adapter.loadObjects();
  }
```

I get the error at "CommentList.setAdapter(Adapter);"

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class CommentListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    private List<String> itemList;
    private Context context;
    public ParseImageView thumbnailFile;
    public TextView UsernameView;
    public TextView Comments;

    public CommentListAdapter(Context context) {
        // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
        // Todos marked as high-pri
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Activity");
                query.whereEqualTo("photoId", CommentActivity.getPhoto());
                query.whereEqualTo("type", "comment");
                query.orderByAscending("created_at");

                Log.e("Log", "Query: " + query.countInBackground().toString());


                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    // Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.comment_list_items, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);


        Log.e("Log", "Comment: " + object.toString());


        thumbnailFile  = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_thumbnail);
        UsernameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        Comments = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);

        String Content = object.toString();

        Comments.setText(Content);


        return v;
    }
}
```

Please help me, this kind of error should occur in such a case, I don't know what to do..

If you need more of my code, just tell me.

Comment: Can you show `ParseQueryAdapter`? It looks like there might be a query going on there.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer I added the adapter. Do you see something?

Comment: Yeah thought so. The ParseQueryAdapter uses a ParseQuery to retrieve the data that it's going to show. It does this when the adapter is created, meaning the adapter can't be used until it has retrieved all data. This is why you're getting the error. It's retrieving data, and you can't continue till it has retrieved this data. Does the error stop the app from working completely? Or does it freeze and continue once the data is loaded?

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer Thank you. It crashes completely. So what should I change?

Comment: In that case that's up to the Parse guys to properly fix. The only thing I can advise is retrieving your data seperately before adding it to a new Adapter. That way you can let your app load your data asynchronously without blocking the UI.